# Angular 2 signaturepad in system JS

Tags: angular, systemjs

Can anyone tell me how do I add the angular2-signaturepad package to SystemJS.config file in the angular 4 project. I am not getting its main file ?

Following is the systemjs.config file and the package name is angular2-signaturepad.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            'ng2-auto-complete': 'npm:ng2-auto-complete/dist/ng2-auto-complete.umd.js',
            'ng2-bootstrap-modal': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap-modal',
            'angular2-busy': 'npm:angular2-busy',
            'file-saver':'npm:file-saver',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './app.main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'Rx.js'
            },
            'ng2-bootstrap-modal': {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-busy': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Please let me know how do I add angular2-signaturepad under map and packages just as I have added other packages. Also, I tried adding it as follows
Under map :

```
'angular2-signaturepad':'npm:angular2-signaturepad'
```

Under packages :

```
'angular2-signaturepad': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
```

But then it throws error as "localhost:3000/signature_pad" not found
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Paste your systemjs.config.js file please

Comment: @FRECIA - for your conveniene, I have added the code of my systemjs.config. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AmitAnand Did you ever resolve this?